# Match specified integers

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have the following regex:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6
```

It's an SQL part, and I want to match only those 6 ids. The problem is that this regex matches also integers like 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 23, etc.

How can I form the regex to match only those 6 specific integers?

Comment: In `SQL` `[[:<:]][123456][[:>:]]`, use boundaries.

Comment: But integers can be greater than 9.

Comment: Yeah, precisely that regex matches exactly **only one** character from that set `[123456]`.

Comment: What kind of SQL server is it? PostgreSQL, MySQL or MSSQL?..

Comment: MySQL, the query goes like "...id REGEX '1|2|3|4|5|6'" and should match 6 rows with these ids.

Comment: So, use `SELECT * FROM t WHERE REGEXP '^[123456]$'`. I think Kasramvd's suggestion was valid, but he deleted the answer.

Comment: What if I have to use `1|2|3|4|5|6|23`?

Comment: Then, you'd use alternation with a character class: `WHERE REGEXP '^([1-6]|23)$'`

Comment: I believe, this should work `'^(1|2|3|4|5|6)$'`

Comment: @domino: Sure, it will. Grouping is key with anchors and alternations.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it now, thanks! It's pretty slow though.

Comment: Why not just using `OR`? Regexps are always slow. In case you have a small subset, I'd rather use a non-regex approach.

Comment: @stribizhev I'm guessing the search parameters are provided in the format specified, hence the need for regex.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use "shorter" queries, you can use alternation with a character class with `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id REGEXP '^([1-6]|23)$'
```

The character class `[1-6]` matches numbers from `1` to `6`, and `|` is used to list other alternatives. Grouping with `(...)` makes the anchors `^` (beginning of string) and `$` (end of string) apply to all possible alternatives.

If your ids are passed separately and the regex is created dynamically, just use alternation:

```
^(23|6|5|4|3|2|1)$
```

However, if you have a small subset of ids, you'd better use `OR` syntax to list your alternatives since non-regex solutions are less resource-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Any reason why you explicitly want to use a REGEXP?
9 out of 10 times there are better solutions instead of a REGEXP